# Discord.py - Sending messages to every member

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Before everyone starts assuming, I have permissions to do this command.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def dm(ctx, *, message=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if message:
        for guilds in bot.guilds:
            members = guilds.members
            for m in members:
                await m.send(message)
                print("Message sent to all")
```

I receive an error:

`Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user`

Because I'm dm-ing every member, some members do have their dms open (I have personally dm'd some members using their ID and it worked)

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the bot is unable to send the DM because the user has their DMs disabled or friends only, You can list the users who didn't get the DMs.

Here is how you can see who didn't get the DMs.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def dm(ctx, *, message=None):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Message sent to all users in this server except the users listed below.")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if message:
        for guilds in bot.guilds:
            members = guilds.members
            for m in members:
                try:
                    await m.send(message)
                except discord.Forbidden: # discord.Forbidden means that the bot can't be sent.
                    await ctx.send(f"{m.name}#{m.discriminator}")
```

I hope this helped, I felt like Kelo's answer wasn't really explaining much so I tried to help and improve the code.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try-except to avoid the error.

```
try:
    await m.send(message)
except:
    pass
```